# Teradata - Median Window Aggregate Function

Tags: sql, teradata

I am looking for a window aggregate function in Teradata. There's one for Average(AVG), MINIMUM(MIN) etc... but I can't seem to find Median. Is there a way I can use the existing function in a windowed operation?

I need something like this:

```
  SEL 
 data_val
 , MEDIAN() OVER (ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS med_data_val
 FROM tab
```

Thanks.

Comment: How interesting.  In most databases, `percentile_disc()` /`percentile_cont()` are *only* window functions.  In Teradata, they are *only* aggregation functions.  Also, your example doesn't include an `order by` or a column for the median. . . sample data and desired results would help.  Are there ties?

Comment: Yes it's strange! And, sorry, I just wanted to give an idea what I'm looking for so didn't include order by. It's a numeric column. And, there may be duplicate values (ties?). Any ideas?

Comment: . . You should ask a question that has appropriate data, desired results, and a clear explanation.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Sorry, about it. I thought it's a common functionality. I am working on preparing a better question.

Comment: Here's a link to an [old but very useful article](https://downloads.teradata.com/blog/dnoeth/2011/06/missing-functions-percentile-disc-percentile-cont-median) on calculating median (among other things) in Teradata.